# How to add sumarry to method

Tags: c#, dll, summary

I have a method like follow,

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts currency
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dtRawInput">Output of the procedure P_FETCH_CONV_CUR</param>
///<param name="FromCurrency">Three letter code of from currency  Ex: USD</param>
///<param name="ToCurrency">Three letter code of from currency  Ex: USD</param>
///<param name="FromAmount">From currency amount  Ex: USD</param>
///<param name="Type">N for normal conversion, F for fare round and T for tax round</param>
/// <exception cref="FormatException">Why it's thrown.</exception>       
public static string CurrencyConversion(DataTable dtRawInput, string FromCurrency, string ToCurrency, string FromAmount, string Type)
{
}
```

When I tried to access this method it is showing summary and param definition on tool tip.

But the problem is

- It is not showing anything once after converting this class into dll.

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not distributing the xml documentation file with your dll. To create the xml documentation file you need to use the visual studio command prompt tool to generate the xml documentation file and run the following command...

```
csc yourclass.cs /doc:out_file.xml
```

This is the hard way to do it. But, since what you want is to generate the xml documentation file for a pile of classes, then you can set this from the Project's Properties page, go to the Build tab and then tick the Xml Documentation File checkbox...see screenshot below...

[image]